# UITableView Cell Color based on contents of cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making a simple app with a tableview that displays results of a test.  The results are coming from a simple array.  In the array there are just numbers, test scores between 0 and 100.

I'm trying to get the UITableView row to change the colour depending on the results.  Above or equal to 75 will display a green background, >= 50 && < 75 will be yellow, > 50 will be red.

This is what I have so far.  My understanding is quite basic.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    // Set up the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:row];

    // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP TO GET THE VALUE FROM THE ARRAY 
    // INTO ????

    if (???? >=75) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    if (???? >=50 && ???? <75) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    if (???? >=0 && ???? <50) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: 
(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;    
}
```

If I just put `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];`, for example, they all go green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the value is displaying correctly in the textLabel, you can use this:

```
 NSInteger score = [cell.textLabel.text intValue];

 if (score >=75) {
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a string representing an integer? If so, use `intValue` to convert to integer. Is it a string representing a float? Use `floatValue`. You don't give any info about what's in the array.

Comment: OK thanks, in the array there are just numbers - test scores.  99, 78, 34, etc.  So do i put 

    intValue = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:row];

?

Comment: What do you mean "just numbers"? You cannot put "just numbers" in an NSArray. You can only put objects in an array. What kind of objects? I presume they are NSString objects; if they weren't, it would be illegal for you to say `cell.textLabel.text = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:row]`. So if they are NSString objects then to use one as an integer you must convert it to an integer with `intValue` as I said, e.g., `[[scoresArray objectAtIndex:row] intValue]`. Look in the NSString docs (if these are NSString objects).